# Create and display indoor map on Android

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm developing an Android application and I would like to display an internal (indoor) map of some buildings, but I don't know where to begin: I want to create a custom kml file (how it's possible to create it? with which tool?) and display it in a fragment.
I already have it working with external maps (simple GoogleMap in MapFragment), so it would be super to have the kml file placed 'over' the GoogleMap, like real indoor maps.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Lorenzo you got proper solution for this ?

Comment: Hi @nilkash. No I haven't got the solution, my project is going on and would continue also in the next months so  I'm still waiting to find something!

Comment: Yeah for me also same thing. Will update you when I get solution.

Comment: I am also getting stuck how to create indoor map. I also tried to search the solution from Internet but I have not got anything yet. Dear @Lorenzo Barbagli , nilkash, have you find out the solution? if yes, could you please share or give me some information so that I can create indoor map. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RichardLe yeas we created own internal maps using open gl and polygon coordinates. But currently those are 2D maps. Zoom and translations every thing is possible in that

Comment: @nilkash: could you please to share more details how to create indoor map or you can give me some tutorial to handle it? 2D is totally OK for me. Thank you

Comment: @RichardLe sir it was big project and it also holds some company credentials. So really sorry for that. I can not share it. But if you really wants then you can start with some opengl basics.

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.

Answer (score 2):

My project is also about indoor maps. I want to share my experience:

First, I tried to use google map but google does not support all countries and my country is not supported. Therefore, I was not able to use google maps although it could be an easy way.

Second, I tried to use open street map which does not render indoor elements. It would be crazy because you have to use lost of other gis tools in order to do it.

the last, I thought why do I need geographical data. All of them - google, osm - are geographical maps which has geographical data. So I do not need this. I rendered my map and I used x,y coordinates of my map's jpg file. I added all of important place's x,y coordinate so I can search them. And it is most easy.  And you can use tileview library which is so easy.

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.