# How to create and display Indoor Map in Android

Tags: android, dictionary, indoor-positioning-system

I want to develop Indoor Position in Android. First of all, I need to create and display an indoor map (floor plan) in Android, then I can carry my own work. However, I do not know how to do that. I found the similar question in StackOverflow [Create and display indoor map on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282075/create-and-display-indoor-map-on-android) but unfortunately it still not have any answer. Anyone can give me the solution?

Thanks

Comment: For those who only want to create and display indoor map without caring about any restriction, can refer to http://movinsoftware.nl/en/developers/